# Kernel Panic at boot: not syncing: attempted to kill init!

Tags: raspbian

I have [BerryBoot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) installed on my Pi, which works as expected.

However when booting into my Raspbian image, the OS fails to initialize with the following output:

```
Mounting image Debian_Wheezy_Raspbian_2012.09.img240...
Mounting RW data directory on top
mount: mounting none on /aufs failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on proc failed: No such file or directory
Starting operating system Debian_Wheezy_Raspbian_2012.09.img240...
BusyBox v1.20.1 (2012-11-25 00:27:52 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: switch_root [-c /dev/console] NEW_ROOT NEW_INIT [ARGS]

Free initramfs and switch to another root fs:
chroot to NEW_ROOT, delete all in /, move NEW_ROOT to /,
execute NEW_INIT. PID must be 1. NEW_ROOT must be a mountpoint.

        -c DEV  Reopen stdio to DEV after switch

[   14.135442] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
[   14.135710] [] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf0) from [] (panic+0x74/0x1a4)
[   14.186689] [] (panic+0x74/0x1a4) from [] (do_exit+0x650/0x748)
[   14.186919] [] (do_exit+0x650/0x748) from [] (do_group_exit+0x40/0xc4)
[   14.187158] [] (do_group_exit+0x40/0xc4) from [] (sys_exit_group+0x10/0x18)
[   14.187476] [] (sys_exit_group+0x10/0x18) from [] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
```

Edit: I think it might because I'm using an old version of BerryBoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating BerryBoot to the latest version fixed the problem.